# Output Web Page as DOCX?

Tags: docx

In the past, if I wanted a web page to display as a .DOC word document, I could do so by doing this in the page load:

```
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FullDetail.doc")
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.word"
```

I was hoping to output the web page as a .DOCX by doing:

```
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FullDetail.docx")
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
```

but it doesn't work. I get an error:

The file FullDetail.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.  The file is corrupt and cannot be opened.

The contents of both files look pretty much identical - just an HTML page.

HR Full Detail Report

etc...

The .doc opens fine.  The .docx doesn't.  If I rename the .docx to .doc, it opens fine in Word 2010.  Any suggestions? 

Thanks!
Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A docx file is actually a zip file that contains several other files.  For example, create a new MS Word doc, put the text "Hello world" in it and save it (example.docx).  Then rename the docx file to "example.zip" and open it.  You will see that a the content is much more complicated than you might have expected.

Most people find that it is much easier to generate a Word XML file (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266220(v=office.12).aspx) or use an API for generating a real docx file (for instance: http://docx.codeplex.com/).